# The process or thread has changed since last step (Visual Studio)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a C# .NET *console application* that sends an email using `SmtpClient`.

I am experiences the following behavior in the code shown below:

1. Set a break point somewhere above line 35
2. Hit the break point, step through line 30, 32, etc.
3. Before it hits line 35, it jumps back up to line 28 again
4. At some point, I get the **"The process or thread has changed since last step"** message
5. The jumping around seems random

[image: The process or thread has changed since last step screen shot]

**Why does my break point jump around?**

**What does that message mean?**

**Is there anything wrong with my code?**

*([Here's another similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863089/the-process-or-thread-has-changed-since-last-step). Probably the same thing, but it's ASP.NET)*

---

*Per Hans Passants's tip follows.*

**This version *still* permits race condition:** Toggle [`Timer.AutoReset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in my timer's event handler to avoid re-entrancy while code is running.

```
private void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  timer.AutoReset = false; // prevent another Elapsed event
  MyClass.SendMail(smtpServer, account, password); // do stuff
  timer.AutoReset = true; // allow another Elapsed event
}
```

**Final version:** Initialize the timer with `AutoReset` already set to false, then call `Timer.Start()` again at the end of your Elapsed event handler.

```
public void Start()
{
  timer = new Timer(checkInterval);
  timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
  timer.AutoReset = false; // prevent race condition
  timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   bool exceptionIsNasty = false;
   try {
      MyClass.SendMail(smtpServer, account, password); // do stuff
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
      // Log exception, set exceptionIsNasty to true if the mailing should be stopped
      //...
   }
   finally {
       if (!exceptionIsNasty) timer.Start();  // allow another Elapsed event
   }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got more than one thread executing the same method and they all hit the same breakpoint.  When you continue stepping, the debugger cannot accurately guess anymore which thread it should show the state for.  So you just get a warning that you are now looking at the state of a different thread. The local variable values are liable to be different. As is the execution location of course, the reason the highlight changes.

Clearly this can make debugging more difficult.  You want to avoid this if you are still getting bugs out of the code, start just one thread.  Beyond that, a temporary workaround is to use Debug + Windows + Threads, right-click one of the threads and select Freeze.  Don't forget to unfreeze again.

Comment: This method is `static`, but I correct in assuming the same thing would happen even if it wasn't, and I had to create a new instance of the object every time I wanted to send an email? Also, am I correct in assuming the reason why I have multiple threads executing the same code is because I have an event firing every 1 second, and every time I *slowly* hit F10, the method is called again by that event?

Comment: Whether it is static or not is not relevant.  Using a Timer to call this method is a very good way to get into this kind of trouble.  If sending an email takes longer than 1 second then you'll get *another* thread started by the timer to run the method.  Very unhealthy.  And inevitable when you single step the method, that of course always takes more than a second.  Do consider the wisdom of sending *eighty thousand* emails a day.  Avoid this re-entrancy by setting the timer's AutoReset property to false.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Have I implemented your suggestion properly? (See update to my question above.) *Btw, the 1 second timer interval was for  testing purposes only. In the real world, my timer is much less frequent.*

Comment: No that's not correct, that still permits a race.  Initialize the timer with AutoReset already set to false.  Call Start() again at the end of your Elapsed event handler.  And watch out for exceptions, they are swallowed without a diagnostic.

Comment: Thanks again! Is the updated code correct now? Does pattern toggle `Timer.Enabled` between true & false?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't run in one thread to debug, or don't want to change something to do it ,
To make debugging easier, You can also break conditionally using 
filter is true ThreadId == xxxxx (right-clicking the breakpoint).

you break in the method you want with a regular breakpoint, look which threadid is the current one (there will be an arrow) in Threads window (Debug - > Windows -> Threads). the next breakpoints could be conditional as I suggested.

note that in a different run the thread id will change and you'll have to update it in Breakpoints window.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the conditional break point where you want to start debugging
2. select all threads from debug>windows>threads then select all threads ctr + A then ctr + click the thread you are current debugging, right click and choose freeze.

Comment: This answer is the same as selected answer.